# Why is there a tag for rails3?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags

There is already a tag for [ruby-on-rails3](/questions/tagged/ruby-on-rails3) used by 7786 questions.
[rails3](/questions/tagged/rails3) is used by 84 questions.

It becomes problematic having those two tags refer to the exact same thing.

Should the [rails3](/questions/tagged/rails3) tag be removed?

Answer (score 1):

They should be (and have already been made from the looks of it) synonyms, although [rails3](/questions/tagged/rails3) is simply more concise and can be directly understood.